# VGA displayport sees monitor as a TV

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, vga

I have a monitor (LG flatron W2353S 24 inches), a Macbook Pro (Late 2011) Model A1278, and a VGA displayport adapter.

The issue is that when I connect my MacBook to my monitor it detects the monitor as a 47" TV.

The cable works and I can use my 1920x1080 native resolution, but it displays wrong. There's a black large line on the left (like 2 centimeters) and on the right you can see that it's missing a part of the screen.

I think it's a driver issue or maybe the monitor is not compatible with this? This monitor only has a VGA port.

Any anyone suggest other things I can try?